# Can you switch verb tenses when beginning a new sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english, tenses, speech

Tony had just **grabbed** another bottle of whiskey when it happened. **Dropping** it, he **reached** out and grabbed the closest thing to him, narrowly avoiding falling to the ground.

Like going from "grabbed" to "dropping" and back to "reached"

Is that allowed or is it right the way it is?

Comment: "Dropping" is not a tense, it is a present participle. Such can be used in conjunction with any tense - a parachutist might say at intervals "I was dropping; I have been dropping; I had been dropping; I am dropping; I will be dropping; I will have been dropping".